# How to determine which registered gradient method is being utilized by the model or graph?

Tags: python, tensorflow

There are several SO posts showing how to create custom gradients using the `tf.custom_gradient` or `tf.RegisterGradient` decorators.

```py
@ops.RegisterGradient("MyCustomGradient")
@tf.custom_gradient("MyCustomGradient")
```

But how do you explicitly look-up which gradient methods are being utilized for your current model or graph?  Looking at `ops._gradient_registry._registry`, there are currently 4 different `Relu` keys:

- `'Relu'`,
- `'Relu6'`,
- `'Relu6Grad'`,
- `'ReluGrad'`.

If I wanted to use a custom gradient in place of `'Relu'`, I've been using:

```py
with g.gradient_override_map({'Relu': 'MyCustomGradient'}):
    ...
```

But how do I find out if `'Relu'` is actually the gradient method my graph or model is currently using?